# Удобное отображение большого количества комментариев.

Tags: комментарии

Как удобно организовать динамический вывод большого количества комментариев с медиа-контентом? 
В вконтакте это сделано крайне неудобно, тем более при большом количестве комментариев с картинками подгружаемых автоматом все будет сильно лагать. Можно сделать постраничное отображение, но как это будет смотреться в древовидном выводе?

Comment: Смотрите в сторону habr.ru или 4chan.org. В livejournal.com и вконтактике и правда паршивая система.

Comment: Пожалуй, к чему-то подобному и приду. В хабре вроде автодогрузки :с